# Appending dynamically created names to a class variable from UI Class

Tags: python, pyqt

I am fairly new to the concepts of OOP. I am having a hard time even wording my question. Maybe the question has been answered already, but worded differently!

I have a class called Create_Capsules(). It has two functions:

1. create a cube
2. create a sphere.

I created a class variable that appends the names of these newly created capsules.

Create Capsule Class (psuedo-code):

```
class Create_Capsule(object):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Create_Capsule, self).__init__()        
        self.user_capsules = []

    def cube(self):
        #psuedo-code
        cap_name = create_cube(name='capsule_cube01')
        self.user_capsules.append(cap_name)
        return cap_name
        
    def sphere(self):
        #psuedo-code
        cap_name = create_sphere(name='capsule_sphere01')        
        self.user_capsules.append(cap_name)        
        return cap_name
```

I have another UI Class that has two simple QPushButtons, Cube and Sphere.
The functions Create_Capsules().cube() and Create_Capsules().sphere() are being called from these buttons.
At the end of this process, I want to be able to query the class variable to get a list of all capsules created.

I tried to create an object of the Create_capsule class in the UI and pass that to the functions when the cube/sphere buttons are clicked.

Excerpts from the UI code:

```
Class toolUI(obj):
    addNewBboxLabel = QLabel("Add New Capsule:")
    user_capsule = Create_Capsule()

    addCubeButton = QPushButton("Cube")
    addCubeButton.clicked.connect(self.addCubeClicked(user_capsule))
    # addCubeButton.clicked.connect(functools.partial(self.addCubeClicked), user_capsule)

    addSphereButton = QPushButton("Sphere")
    addSphereButton.clicked.connect(self.addSphereClicked(user_capsule))
    # addSphereButton.clicked.connect(functools.partial(self.addSphereClicked), user_capsule)
    
    def addCubeClicked(self, capsule_obj):
        """
        Adds a cube to the scene 
        """               
        user_cube = capsule_obj.cube()   
        print(user_cube)            
        print(capsule_obj.user_capsules)

    def addSphereClicked(self, capsule_obj):
        """
        Adds a sphere to the scene 
        """               
        user_sphere = capsule_obj.sphere()   
        print(user_sphere)             
        print(capsule_obj.user_capsules)
```

On executing this, on opening the UI, a cube is being created (even without clicking the cube button in UI). And, I get this error message:

> addCubeButton.clicked.connect(self.addCubeClicked(user_capsule))
>
> RuntimeError: Failed to connect signal clicked()

I can choose to not bother about the class variable approach, and instead return the name of the capsule from the addCubeClicked() and addSphereClicked() functions, collect them in the UI and append a list there. But, that feels dirty as I don't want to clutter up my UI function with any other logic.
I feel like I am missing a key concept of OOP here.

Comment: change `addCubeButton.clicked.connect(self.addCubeClicked(user_capsule))` to `addCubeButton.clicked.connect(lambda *args, user_capsule=user_capsule : self.addCubeClicked(user_capsule))`

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `toolUI` class, you should wrap your code inside a method, such as `__init__`. You may also want to add `self.` to your widgets.

```
class toolUI(obj):
    def __init__(self):
        self.addNewBboxLabel = QLabel("Add New Capsule:")
        self.user_capsule = Create_Capsule()

        self.addCubeButton = QPushButton("Cube")
        self.addCubeButton.clicked.connect(self.addCubeClicked(self.user_capsule))

        self.addSphereButton = QPushButton("Sphere")
        self.addSphereButton.clicked.connect(self.addSphereClicked(self.user_capsule))
```

Part of the reason was that your code didn't exist with an unique instance of the class, and `self` was not a defined variable. Placing it inside a method with a `self` param will define that variable for use and also allow other methods to access properties belonging to that object (e.g. `self.addCubeButton`).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. The user_capsule was indeed inside a def __init__(self). I just forgot to mention that. But., I did add the self to the variables and the widgets as you suggested. But, I am still getting the same issue. The use of lambda, as suggested by @eyllanesc does work however and does what I need. Thanks for your suggestions again. I am still curious as to why the method you suggested did not work for me. Will reply back, if I find out why